# XAMPP: keeps aborting mysql, I don't know what's wrong

Tags: mysql, xampp

It's the first time I'm using XAMPP and when I run XAMPP and start the mysql it keeps aborting it.
I don't know if something is missing on my drivers and I've checked and updated my drivers and the same thing happened, I still got the same error. It says
[ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?

[ERROR] Aborting

here's the [XAMPP log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07KTa.png)

Here's my mysql_error.log

```
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  8:55:47 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300306; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  9:05:21 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300315; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  9:10:27 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300324; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  9:10:34 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300333; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  9:20:30 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300342; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  9:21:20 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300351; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  9:22:15 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300360; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  9:34:22 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300369; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  9:34:32 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300378; transaction id 170
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-07-31  9:36:31 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced something similar back when I installed MySQL community after Xampp on Windows. So assuming you're on Windows:

1. CTRL + R, type in services.msc
2. Stop all mysql services that are running
3. Start MySQL on Xampp

If this worked, then that means you have 2 MySQL installations (1 of which is from Xampp) and both are listening on Port 3306 as the error message suggests. Change one of them to listen on another port, 3307 or something.